# Nginx reverse proxy doesnt not appear to be working when Node http-server running

Tags: node.js, nginx, httpserver

I have a server with two two Single Page Application (using a framework) running using node http-server:

```
website1 running on port 80: IP_ADDRESS:80  
website2 running on port 8080: IP_ADDRESS:8080
```

Currently the workflow is using this two commands to deploy the two sites

```
pm2 start /usr/bin/http-server -f --name website1 -- -p 80 -d false  
pm2 start /usr/bin/http-server -f --name website2 -- -p 8080 -d false
```

At the end, our sites run on domain like this:

```
subdomain.mysite.com for website1  
subdomain.mysite.com:8080 for website2.
```

This is not desired, we wanted like this:

```
subdomain.mysite.com for website1  
subdomain2.mysite.com for website2
```

I tried to install nginx, with the follow reverse proxy configurations:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name subdomain2.mysite.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

Hoping that now, if I type subdomain2.mysite.com, it will bring me to the website2 on port 8080, but it didn't, it brings me to website1 on port 80 instead. In fact, I cant be sure if this reverse proxy is working at all.

I am sure I configured something wrongly, what could be the problem?

p/s: I also wonder if I am doing it entirely wrong - if I am using nginx for reverse proxy, should I stop using http-server directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node and Nginx can't both listen on port 80 at the same time. If you want to reverse proxy both you'll need to use a different port for the first Node app and add another virtual host to your nginx file for it.

For example, changing the first app's port to 8000 would look like:

```
pm2 start /usr/bin/http-server -f --name website1 -- -p 8000 -d false
pm2 start /usr/bin/http-server -f --name website2 -- -p 8080 -d false
```

With the following Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name subdomain2.mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name subdomain1.mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

You probably also want to add the `proxy_redirect off;` flag to each block.

Comment: Thank you so much!!